# What form and how much advertising is permitted on the jersey of players and the referee?

Tags: football

I am finding difficulty interpreting The Laws for this regard.

1. They don't mention anything about advertising/logos on the referee's jersey.
2. Moreover, they [mention](http://theifab.com/laws/the-players-equipment/chapters/equipment-slogans-statements-images-and-advertising) "*only* logos of manufacturer are permitted on undergarments of players". But they don't mention about advertising on the main shirt. I also noticed [this image](https://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/5711323d2200002900253a64.jpeg?ops=scalefit_720_noupscale) which shows the particular player wearing Qatar Airways and Nike on his shirt.

Comment: The laws don't mention it because the laws don't cover it. Anything outside the game itself is placed under regulations of the particular body governing the competition.

Comment: @Nij But isn't it still football? Or, so i thought... Who covers adverts, then? Can you give me a link to set my search up?

Comment: Well, no. Advertising isn't football. Neither is how to film and broadcast a match, or print programmes and tickets, or sell food and drink to spectators... Just because it's happening at a football game doesn't mean it's part of the game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question's answers will vary from one organizing institution to another (UEFA/FIFA/etc.).

Comment: As mentioned above, please clarify which level of the game you're talking about. Any particular country's league, international games, friendly games??

Comment: @alamoot I was talking about international games.

Comment: @GaurangTandon the image you provided is of Lionel Messi in Barcelona uniform. That wouldn't be an international game

Comment: @alamoot oh! I didn't know that. it was just an image that came in google search. thanks for letting me know!